# Unity3d View not update when integrating into react-native

Tags: unity-game-engine, react-native

I am a beginner with react-native and android, I try to integrate unity view into react-native, and I follow the RN Docs to do sth.
[The Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html)

Everything looks OK, the UnityView is shown up. But the problem is, Unity is not updated, it looks like paused.

Maybe something i ignored ?

Some code :

```
public UnityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    ...

    // AddUnityView
    mUnityPlayer = UnityManager.instance().getUnityPlayer();
    LinearLayout mParent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.realView);
    View mView=mUnityPlayer.getView();
    mParent.addView(mView);
    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    ...}
```

```html
    'use strict'  
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { View } from 'react-native';  
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';  
  
class UnityView extends Component {  
  setNativeProps(props){  
    this.root.setNativeProps(props);  
  }  
  render() {  
    return (  
      <UnityViewNative  
        {...this.props}  
        style={[  
          {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},  
          this.props.style,  
        ]}   
        ref={(r)=>{this.root = r}}  
      />  
    );  
  }  
}  
  
UnityView.propTypes = {  
  
};  
  
const UnityViewNative = requireNativeComponent('RCTUnityView', UnityView);  
  
export default UnityView;
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The unity player might actually be paused.

You could try this...

```
mUnityPlayer.resume();
```